# How to change Ubuntu DHCP server address on the client?

Tags: networking, server, 14.04, virtualbox, dhcp

How do I tell Ubuntu to use a specific DHCP server IP? I'm building a virtual test network in VirtualBox where I have a Ubuntu server installed. However, VirtualBox doesn't have an option to tell other computers to use a specific VM IP as the DHCP server.

Comment: You mean you want to use a static IP? Or do you have 2 dhcp servers on the same LAN?

Comment: @meccooll I want to set the clients to use a specific DHCP server. Normally the router tells the computers what DHCP and DNS servers to use, but in VirtualBox this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default VirtualBox network mode, NAT, will not allow this. It creates a virtual network between the host and the guest, it doesn't connect the guest directly to the real network.

You are probably looking for Bridged networking. It will connect the virtual machine to the same network as the host, allowing it to use the same DHCP server and have an IP addresses in the same range.

You should set this in Virtual Box preferences, network tab:

[image]

You can also use NAT Network, a new experimental mode where all the Virutal Machines share a (virtual too) network. By default NAT Network offers it's own DHCP server, you can disable it from the command line:

```
VBoxManage natnetwork modify -t nat-int-network -h off
```

Where nat-int-network is your internal network name (this is just the default value)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'm using NAT Network in VirtualBox. This creates a virtual network for all the VMs. Compared to Internal Network, this also allows VMs to access the internet. I don't want the VMs to be in the same network as the physical machines.

Comment: Then, if you just disable the VB server ('VBoxManage natnetwork modify -t nat-int-network -h off') your server should take care. The first argument is the network name, you should change it.

Comment: Thanks! Disabling the built in DHCP server did the trick. But why do the other computers automatically pick up that server then? And, please add it in the answer so I can mark it correct.

Comment: You don't need to configure a DHCP server in the clients never. Client computers broadcast a message to the net asking for leases and server(s) answer.